# colorSelect function passing alt tag to input field

Tags: jquery, function, click

I believe I have 90% of the code complete. What I am trying to achieve is creating a reusable function for any purpose. The role of the function is that when the user selects a color swatch the alt tag on the img is sent to the input field.  I seem to be having a issue with the actual function itself, as nothing seems to happen when I click on a color.  Currently this works as a Jquery program, but i am now trying to build it as a function as part of our library. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/8vs6R/1/)

Jquery

colorSelect = function () {

```
var colorval = $('#FIELD_').val();
$(this).find('img[alt="' + colorval + '"]').addClass('color-field-selected');
    var colortitle = $(this).attr('alt');
    $(this).addClass('color-field-selected').siblings().removeClass('color-field-selected');

    $('#FIELD_').attr('value', colortitle);

    return false;
```

};
$(function(){

```
  $('.color-field img').on( 'click',colorSelect());
```

});

HTML

```
<div class="color-field">
  <div class="color-size">
<img border="0" src="http://www.pflivedevelopment.com/custom/tabs_custom_skin/images/black.jpg" title="PMS Black 185" alt="Black">
<img border="0" src="http://www.pflivedevelopment.com/custom/tabs_custom_skin/images/green.jpg" title="Green PMS 347" alt="Green">
 <img border="0" src="http://www.pflivedevelopment.com/custom/tabs_custom_skin/images/blue.jpg" title="Blue PMS 300" alt="Blue">
 <img border="0" src="http://www.pflivedevelopment.com/custom/tabs_custom_skin/images/red.jpg" title="Red PMS 185" alt="Red">
   </div>
    <input id="Field_" type="text">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.color-size {
height: 45px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.color-size img {
cursor: pointer;
}
.color-field-selected {
```

border: 2px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8vs6R/5/

You shoud use `$('.color-field img').on('click', colorSelect); // <-- Removed ()`

 and your ID is not `#FIELD_` but `#Field_` ;)

```
colorSelect = function () {

    var colorval = $('#Field_').val();
    $(this).find('img[alt="' + colorval + '"]').addClass('color-field-selected');
    var colortitle = $(this).attr('alt');
    $(this).addClass('color-field-selected').siblings().removeClass('color-field-selected');

    $('#Field_').attr('value', colortitle);

    return false;
};
$(function () {

    $('.color-field img').on('click', colorSelect);
});
```

---

**You have a bunch of useless stuff and logic in there.** 
 To simplify your code do like:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vs6R/10/

```
function colorSelect() {
    $(this).addClass('color-field-selected').siblings().removeClass('color-field-selected');
    $('#Field_').val(this.alt) ;
}


$(function () {
    $('.color-field img').on('click', colorSelect);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are setting the result of the function as the handler instead of setting the function reference itself to the handler.

Here the function will be invoked as you bind the handler and attach the result as the handler for the function which in your case is a boolean value.

Change:

```
$('.color-field img').on( 'click',colorSelect());
```

to

```
$('.color-field img').on( 'click',colorSelect);
```

Plus the selectors are case sensitive as well so `#FIELD_` != `#Field_`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2bPY/)**

Comment: Using a ecommerce program, forgot to set it to lower case